# Parse cookies & POST data to SetEnv with RewriteRule

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have an odd issue. I need to set an environment variable based on either a POST value or a cookie.* I have figured out how to set an environment variable to the entire cookie string:

```
RewriteRule .* - [E=VAR1:%{HTTP_COOKIE}]
```

However I can't figure out:

1. How to parse out a single cookie value (`username`)
2. How to access specific POST fields
3. How to set up a RewriteCond to set `VAR1` depending on if the value is in the cookie or the POST field

Any thoughts?

*Here's a deeper explanation. I'm using an application that sends the username field as a POST value when the user logs in. Then, the server sets the username as a cookie, and it is sent with each subsequent request. I need to capture the username and set it as an environment variable.

**EDIT**
I figured out the first point:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} ^.*username=([^;]+)
RewriteRule .* - [E=VAL1:%1]
```

Comment: We cannot read POST data in .htaccess as it is retrieved from standard input only. Reading a specific cookie value is surely possible.

Comment: Yup, that's what I was afraid of. I did a little more searching and determined that this was likely the case. Thanks, though!